# Unable to initialize an object through constructors in Java: Erroneous Compilation

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

This code below keeps throwing the following error:
[Java Error Terminal Screen Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qurDI.jpg)

> I've tried quite a few online fixes but they don't seem to be working.
> My code is below and I've commented the error location(occurs in the driver main function)
>
> NOTE: The code compiles properly if I change **public static void main(String args[])** to **public void main(String args[])** but when i run it, it throws the error "**Change main to static void main**". I'm a little stuck here.

```
import java.util.*;
class Exercise{ //Exercise Begins
    class UtilityFunctions{
        public String getAuthor(){ return "";};
        public String  getPublisher(){return "";};
        public void display(){};
    }

class Book extends UtilityFunctions{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String category;
    private String datePublished;
    private String publisher;
    private double price;

    public Book(String authorParam, String publisherParam){
        author = authorParam;
        publisher = publisherParam;
    }
    //List of Setters
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setCategory(String cat){
        this.category = cat;
    }
    public void setDatePublished(String dp){
        this.datePublished = dp;
    }
    public void setPrice(double p){
        this.price = p;
    }

    //List of Getters
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }
    @Override
    public String getAuthor(){
        return this.author;
    }
    public String getCategory(){
        return this.category;
    }
    public String getDatePublished(){
        return this.datePublished;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPublisher(){
        return this.publisher;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }
    @Override
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Book Title:" + getTitle());
        System.out.println("Author:" + getAuthor());
        System.out.println("Category:" + getCategory());
        System.out.println("Date Published:" + getDatePublished());
        System.out.println("Publisher:" + getPublisher());
        System.out.println("Price:$" + getPrice());
    }
}

class Author extends UtilityFunctions{
    private String authorName;
    private String birthDate;
    private String publisher;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    List<Book> bookList;

    public Author(String publisherParam){
        publisher = publisherParam;
    }

    public void addBook(Book b){
        bookList.add(b);
    }
    //List of Setters
    public void setName(String n){
        this.authorName = n;
    }
    public void setEmail(String em){
        this.email = em;
    }
    public void setGender(String gen){
        this.gender = gen;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(String dob){
        this.birthDate = dob;
    }
    //List of Getters
    public String getAuthor(){
        return this.authorName;
    }
    public String getPublisher(){
        return this.publisher;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }
    public String getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }
    public String getBirthDate(){
        return this.birthDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Author Name:" + getAuthor());
        System.out.println("Email:" + getEmail());
        System.out.println("Gender:" + getGender());
        System.out.println("BirthDate:" + getBirthDate());
        System.out.println("Publisher:" + getPublisher());

        System.out.println("BOOKS:");
        for(Book b:bookList){
            b.display();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }   

}

class Publisher extends UtilityFunctions{
    private String publisherName;
    private String publisherAddress;
    private String publisherEmail;
    private int publisherPhoneNumber;
    List<Author> authorList;

    public Publisher(String name, String add, String email,int phone){
        publisherName = name;
        publisherAddress = add;
        publisherEmail = email;
        publisherPhoneNumber = phone;
    }
    public void addAuthor(Author a){
        authorList.add(a);
    }
    //List of Getters
    public String getPublisher(){
        return this.publisherName;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return this.publisherAddress;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return this.publisherEmail;
    }
    public int getPhoneNumber(){
        return this.publisherPhoneNumber;
    }
    @Override
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Publisher Name:" + getPublisher());
        System.out.println("Publisher Address:" + getAddress());
        System.out.println("Publisher Phone Number:" + getPhoneNumber());
        System.out.println("Publisher Email:" + getEmail());

        System.out.println("AUTHORS:");
        for(Author a:authorList){
            a.display();
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    }

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Publisher> publisherList = new ArrayList<Publisher>();
    //1st ERROR HERE
    Publisher pub1 = new Publisher("Riverhead Books","8080 Cross Street","riverhead@riverheadbooks.co.uk",784646533);
    //2nd ERROR HERE
    Author author1 = new Author(pub1.getPublisher());
    author1.setName("Khaled Hosseini");
    author1.setGender("Male");
    author1.setBirthDate("1965-10-09");
    author1.setEmail("khaledhosseini@gmail.com");
    pub1.addAuthor(author1);

    //3rd ERROR HERE
    Book book1 = new Book(author1.getAuthor(),author1.getPublisher());
    book1.setTitle("Kite Runner");
    book1.setCategory("Historical-Fiction|Drama");
    book1.setPrice(39.95);
    book1.setDatePublished("2003-05-29");
    author1.addBook(book1);

    publisherList.add(pub1);
    for(Publisher p:publisherList){
        p.display();
    }
}
```

}//Exercise Ends

Comment: Make every class a top-level class, defined in its own, separate file. You're using inner classes, but you don't understand when and how to use them yet (and there's no good reason here).

Comment: Also, your UtilityFunctions class makes little sense, and there is really no reason for an Author class to have a method getAuthor() (for example). You'd better drop that class, and learn more about inheritance.

Comment: Yes, I did think many times of dropping the UtilityFunctions class. However, the Author represents an entity so it should have its own class right? My goal is to print out for each publisher, all their authors and all the books for each author.

Comment: Yes, it should have its own class. The class you should drop is UtilityFunctions, not Author.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the suggestion about making every class a top-level class and also about the UtilityFunctions class. I'll incorporate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your classes : **Book, Author, Publisher, UtilityFunctions** ... should be *outside* the **Exercise** class

```
Class Exercise {
  public static void main(String args[]) {...}
} // end class exercice

Class UtilityFunctions {...}
Class Book {...}
Class Author {...}
Class Publisher  {...}
```